# Cannot Add to LobSystemInstance properties in BDC Explorer

Tags: visual-studio

I am following exercises in a SP2010 Visual Studio 2010 book and I am using SP 2010 Foundations only.  I am at the point (External Content Types) with my Model where I want to add the name value pair in the property editor for my LobSystemInstance. So, under Custom properties (Collection) I click the ellipses to view the property editor.  Regardless of what I do, I get a red exclamation icon and the Add and OK buttons are grayed out as soon as I click on any field within.  Hovering over the icon tells me to "Please enter a value".  As a further note, I notice this same behavior any time I click on the ellipses for other Custom Properties.

Comment: Figure 10 (along with the text above it) in this article http://mscerts.programming4.us/sharepoint/Sharepoint%202010%20%20%20Creating%20a%20_NET%20Connector%20in%20Visual%20Studio%202010%20%28part%202%29%20-%20BDC%20Modeling%20Tools%20%20%20Defining%20the%20BDC%20Model.aspx shows what I am attempting. On this step, after clicking the ellipses, as soon as I activate the row for typing, the buttons are grayed out and a red icon with the exclamation point appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, you must press "Enter" after putting in the Name property for it to stick. I was entering the name and then using tab.  That's it. The OK button would not enable when using tab.